# Installing krb5-user on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kerberos, apt

Currently I am using:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
```

When installing krb5-user, I got:

http://pastebin.com/9qJhjB5m

Can someone give me hint ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
apt-get update
```

and the re-run the package installation.

Comment: @Ted, since we've answered your question please mark it as such (click the grey check mark) which will verify it to others in the community.